# Stripe PaymentIntents + Subscription

Tags: stripe-payments

Anyone know how to make a Stripe subscription charge a card automatically on future period payments using the new PaymentsIntent SCA approach?

Stripe's docs are in need of major pruning. I've never seen such convoluted and confusing docs as these ones.

One of the confusing parts is where they say in the docs for PaymentsIntents:

```
confirmation_method:

automatic
(Default) PaymentIntent can be confirmed using a publishable key. After next_actions are handled, no additional confirmation is required to complete the payment.

manual
All payment attempts must be made using a secret key. The PaymentIntent returns to the requires_confirmation state after handling next_actions, and requires your server to initiate each payment attempt with an explicit confirmation.
```

If I put automatic, the handleCardAction doesn't work anymore on the front end. If it has to be manual, does that mean that all future recurring payments (say Month 2, 3, etc) will need some kind of SCA confirmation by the user?

I haven't found any elements examples for paymentintents and subscriptions with SCA and varying plans and prices not pre-set on the backend as they depend on each individual's parameters.

If I use manual and handleCardAction, the subscription stays incomplete, despite the payment going through. If I use confirmCardPayment, the SCA popup never shows.

Looking further into the subscription and intent objects, I noticed that a new subscription created on the server comes with its own paymentIntent object. So does it mean one has to stop creating a separate paymentIntent with own id? If you do, it doesn't work for completing the subscription, which stays as incomplete.

However, the subscription's paymentIntent has a confirmation_method set as automatic by default -- this results in an error after SCA on the frontend: "You cannot confirm this PaymentIntent because it has already succeeded after being previously confirmed". Interesting, why did it ask for the SCA then in the status: "requires_action"?? Are we supposed to change manually the confirmation_method on a subscription to "manual"??

All this is quite confusing how to make subscription / paymentIntent work with SCA.

My logic is simple: user customises a subscription and enters card details, all of which gets sent to the server => Server creates a new plan, product, customer and subscription => Sends intent (from Subscription?) back to FE => If required, SCA is performed and the subscription is confirmed. Is this not how it's supposed to be done? I don't have pre-set plans as they can vary. I just need the ability to charge a user automatically the same amount they paid for the next period.

The examples and docs I've seen so far don't address the above use case. If anyone knows how to do it or can point to an example of how stripe elements and paymentIntents work with SCA and subscriptions that actually works and activates the subscription?

Comment: I agree with the sentiment you state about Stripe. It used to be so smooth and sharp but seems to have ballooned into a verbose mess. Their subscription system is not very clean. I have worked on their subscription system but don't have a clean answer for you (I may be able to dig out out at work). I found the best solution was usually to directly email this exact question to Stripe Customer Support. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, emailed them, let's see if they can square the circle :)

Answer (score 1):

Stripe has [a complete guide to fixed-price Subscriptions with Elements](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/fixed-price) that sounds like it covers what you're trying to do.

When you're working with Stripe Billing (Subscriptions and Invoices) you rarely need to interact with the underlying Payment Intents; those are an implementation detail inside of each Invoice.

Comment: I've been through this example several times. It doesn't fit what I am building. It has a couple of fixed plans. In my case there are thousands of plans that need to be created on the backend together with the subscription. 

It's all the more confusing why they are talking about Intents ON TOP OF subscriptions. In any event, even if one just uses subscription payment intents, why are they set at confirmation automatic by default. This renders the SCA useless as the system then complains "You cannot confirm this PaymentIntent because it has already succeeded after being previously confirmed"

Comment: Payment Intents can only be successfully confirmed once.  A Payment Intent represents a customers intent to pay a single time, and once they succeed the Payment Intent cannot be reused for another payment.  Are you using Stripe's Subscriptions or your own subscriptions logic on your end?

Comment: Also, if the payment intent is tied to each periodic invoice, not the whole subscription, are we supposed to run SCA on each and every invoice payment? That'd be a nightmarish scenario to have to chase the user to authenticate their card on a regular basis. The whole point of the subscription is to remove this hassle. Have you implemented this in production?

Comment: Stripe Billing handles a lot regarding SCA for you.  It sounds like you're taking concepts that apply to one-time payments with Payment Intents and trying to apply them to Stripe Billing, which is causing some confusion.  I recommend you read [Stripe's SCA migration guide for Billing](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/migration/strong-customer-authentication) which covers how Billing has changed to accommodate SCA.

Comment: When you say Stripe's subscriptions, you mean if I run stripe.subscriptions.create({,..})?
yes I do. I am trying to follow their examples for https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment-synchronously and setting up subscriptions on the backend returning an intent that needs to be confirmed with SCA if required. It's not a huge ask, but doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Yes, that link is what could help if it had an example. So far, there are many incompatible messages in their docs and my simple use case is falling between the cracks. I wonder where I am doing it wrong that subscription intent is not working. Should it be adjusted to use a paymentintent proper instead perhaps. They should really simplify these docs.

Comment: Yeah, the guide you're following (https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment-synchronously) is for non-Subscription payments.  Pretty much everything there is abstracted away when you're using Stripe Billing/Subscriptions/Invoices.  You can tell broadly what a Stripe doc applies to by looking at the URL: `stripe.com/docs/payments/*` are things for one-time payments, and `stripe.com/docs/billing/*` are things for Billing/Subscriptions/Invoices.

Comment: Yes, I noticed it that their docs are a maze. As far as I can tell, their 2-plan example is different from mine in that it goes back and forth between the front end and the back end, while it is just the same as I have with the subscription intent: subscription.latest_invoice.payment_intent;
I still have the issue of that "You cannot confirm this PaymentIntent because it has already succeeded after being previously confirmed" even though it's the one and only time that I confirm the SCA

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226458/discussion-between-vlad-and-justin-michael).

Comment: Ah, sorry, I'm not available to chat, but if you [contact Stripe Support](https://support.stripe.com/contact) they should be able to help you further!

Comment: It's stackoverflow's default message asking to continue in chat as they don't want too many comments in the Q&A. Nevermind, I've tried to resolve the issue in a different way